# Do multiple instances of my app appear as one to ShoutCast?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, shoutcast

I've written an app that a streams from a shout cast server using an `AVPlayer` object. I've gotten complaints of unreliability from listeners.

I've spoken to the folks behind the stream and they claim that they only see about 300 listeners at any given time and that their server can handle about 1,000 listeners before maxing out. According to flurry analytics, I have at least 1,500 active users and about a month ago, when we explored this issue, there were over 4,000 active listeners.

Is it possible that Shoutcast is lumping listeners together? Is there a way to force Shoutcast to register the correct number of listeners? (Perhaps by changing the user agent to a random string. Is there a way to force AVPlayer to change its user-agent string? How?)

Answer (score 0):

Each client appears separately to a SHOUTcast server.  It's no different than if you had 100 people listening with Windows Media Player... they each take a different connection.

You can expect your analytics for streams and your app to be different.  Just because someone is using your app doesn't mean they are listening to a stream.  If you are sure you are tracking correctly, what you describe could be connectivity problems to the SHOUTcast server.

I would put up a few other SHOUTcast servers as backups in different regions, and verify that your reconnection logic is working properly across many devices.  Also know that streaming over mobile connections does not work well with SHOUTcast streams due to a fixed size buffer that is flushed to the clients upon connect.  With mobile devices, I usually set a large buffer of at least 512KB.

Comment: So you'd set the buffer on the mobile side or on the web side?

Comment: @Moshe You can't set the buffer with SHOUTcast.  I set the buffer by running my own custom software (AudioPump) instead of SHOUTcast.  You can also use Icecast... set the `burst-size` option.

Comment: But you do it server side, and not in the iOS app.

Comment: @Moshe That's correct.  The idea is that the server will send a large buffer, filling the client's buffer as much as possible.  Some devices will accept all this data, some will not.  In any case, cell phone connections periodically drop out and have very high latency.  If the buffer is full client-side, you can survive some of these dropouts.